# jquery scroll and click outside of the div and hide the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an effect. When user click the div Check, it will scroll to #basket-page and it will show, and when user click outside, #basket-page will hide. The only issue is that when user click the div Check first time, #basket-page show and hide immediately, if I click second time, or third time, it has no problem. What can I do to fix this.

```js
jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e)
 {
     var container = jQuery("#basket-page");
     if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
         && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
     {
         container.fadeOut();
     }
 });
 
 jQuery('#checkout_top').click(function(){
  var basket_page=jQuery('#basket-page');
  jQuery('#top_basket').html(basket_page);
  
  var position = jQuery("#myshop_wrap").position();
  scroll(0,position.top);
  jQuery("#basket-page").show();
 });
```

```html
<div id="#checkout_top">Check</div>

<div id="basket-page"></div>
```

Comment: Does this code do anything for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want a check div that you can click on and it will show and scroll you to the basket-page div. I believe the correct way is not to use the scroll() function but to animate the top of your body to the top of your #basket-page div

this should work

```
jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = jQuery("#basket-page");
    var checkoutcontainer = jQuery('#checkout-top');
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0  // ... nor a descendant of the container
    &&
    !checkoutcontainer.is(e.target)) //nor the checkout box itself

    {
        container.fadeOut(1000);
    }
});

jQuery('#checkout-top').click(function () {
    jQuery('#basket-page').show();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#basket-page").offset().top
    }, 1600);

});
```

[Check out this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pw26r4u/1/) I added some css for colors and to make the code work. I also added a little part in the mouseup event, so it includes a check if a click occurs in the checkout div as well.

NB: I encourage you to use the dash '-' instead of the underscore '_' in your class and ID names. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names) for a discussion on this

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try using delay only :

```
 $('#checkout_top').click(function(){
            var basket_page=$('#basket-page');
            $('#top_basket').html(basket_page);

            var position = $("#myshop_wrap").position();
            scroll(0,position.top);
             $("#basket-page").delay(time in ms).show();
            });
```

Comment: Did you import the JQuery library ? If you do replace JQuery by a $

Comment: I don't know why, I use wordpress, I have to use jquery instead of $.

Comment: The problem may come from that. You can add your libraries in wordpress check here for exemple : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321